# TTL bluehost 4 hour time is instant for Create,update,delete on phpmyadmin but takes around 15 minutes to read from phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, swift, xcode, phpmyadmin

I have an account on bluehost and want to be able to read records instantly from phpmyadmin through php. I have already checked that the TTL is 4 hours to update to the website. Although it doesn't always take this long. I was wondering how to get around this to where I can read my database in phpmyadmin and run CRUD commands instantly to phpmyadmin.

Is there a tutorial on how to handle this delay in time to read data from phpmyadmin (like storing data locally and updating it later by an ID) in xcode-swift, in php, or if there is a setting in bluehost to decrease this time from 4 hours...

Or if there is an option to export directly from phpmyadmin. not sure why it takes so long if phpmyadmin can run it instantly.

This is my website:

```
 https://mlbroadvisions.com/service.php
```

the connection between phpmyadmin and this website that's reading my data is slow. Is this because of TTL DNS propagation or can I improve this connection spead?

Comment: What "TTL" are you talking about here? Usually that term gets used when it comes DNS entries, but that can't have anything to do with your issue here.

Comment: Interesting, I was last told that my TTL for my DNS and yes I was referring to my DNS was causing the slow load times to propagate but that doesn't make any since to me because it doesn't take 4 hours to update my website. That's why I asked this question. I figured it was something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS has to do with translating a domain to an IP.  That is used only when connecting.  Normally it 'never' changes.

Maybe you are looking at the TTL for DNS, it is 4 hours.  This is how long that it *might* take from the time when you change xx.yy.com from being 111.222.33.44 to 123.234.45.56.  Did you really do such a thing?

Phpmyadmin should be connecting directly to the database.  It is probably connecting to xx.yy.com.  The first time it may spend a second or so to look up 111.222.33.44.  But after that, that mapping is cached all over the place.  Future lookups should sub-second, or even sub-millisecond.

Similarly for the "reading" device.

Any delays between `INSERTing (on one machine)` and `SELECTing (on another machine)` should be essentially zero.  (Actually, usually milliseconds.)